# What is the best way to replace values/template "keys" in html in with node?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, templates, express

i want to replace values in my html with node express.
for ex,

the html:

```
<html>
<p> hello {guestName} </p>
</html>
```

I wanna replace the `{guestName}` inside my express app. i have a function that getting the right values , now how can do it? until now i cant find a nice way to do it. thank u!

Comment: How do you render the html? I would start there and look into some template language.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the closest thing as far as template engines goes is [`ejs`](https://github.com/tj/ejs).

To use `ejs`, first `npm install ejs`. Then add this to your Express app code:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
// this allows you to render .html files as templates in addition to .ejs
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

In your route handler you just do something like:

```
res.render('hello', { guestName: 'Foo' });
```

and then your template (e.g. `./views/hello.html`) would look like:

```html
<html>
<p> hello <%= guestName %> </p>
</html>
```

Comment: i forgot to say that i want to send it as email , so i cant use res.